# How to run database migrations on new database in Azure?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

After deploying me app to Azure, I have created the new database but now I do not know how to run the EF database migrations. In my published files I have a web.config file which contains the `<environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Production" />` which based on other posts should suffice for running the migrations.

I have made sure my connection string is correct and I can successfully create the connection to the Azure database.

I have no idea what to do next to get my database populated? I have been at this second day now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you add a migration, you can apply it either *manually* by running a PS cmd `Update-Database` or *automatically* when your app launches by having code `myDbCtx.Database.Migrate()` in your `Startup.cs`.

Before you apply your migration, you want to make sure connection string is pointing to the correct database. If you are using Asp.net Core, your connection string is inside `appsettings.json`, and this value can be overridden by your Azure App Service, Application settings.

After you applied your migration, in the `__EFMigrationsHistory` table there will be a row inserted for `MigrationId` and `ProductVersion`. Test everything locally first before going to prod.

Also check out the [EF Migrations docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/). Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey thanks for answering! For local development, I have been updating my database schema manually running the `update` command. However for Azure would I do the same in the CMD or PS? I guess that is my disconnect. Locally I go to the DataAccess project, add migrations and run them. In Azure, Im a little bit confused how it all connects?

Comment: If you run Update-Database locally against your Azure database, make sure your connection string is pointing to it in your appsettings.json. Alternatively you can run Script-Migration locally first to have a .sql script generated, then open up SqlServer Management Studio and run the .sql against your Azure database. I've also done applying migrations automatically with code like I mentioned above on Azure, I have a post written for that https://fanray.com/blog/post/18. So all three ways could work.